# flaskr tutorial; can't import flaskr (initialize database)

Tags: python, import, flask

I'm new to programming, and tried to work through the flask tutorial.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/

I'm stuck on this part (from the readme on github) when trying to run the app:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr/

Fire up a python shell and run this:

```
from flaskr import init_db; init_db()
```

I get this error when I try to run the command in python shell:

```
Import error: No module named flaskr
```

And I get this error when I try to run app locally:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I've been looking for solution for several hours now, but to no avail.
Any thoughts on what I could check?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish what you need is to fire up the Python shell in the same folder as you have flaskr:

```
# I'm assuming that python is available on the command line
$ cd path/to/flaskr
$ python

# Python then runs and you can import flaskr
>>> from flaskr import init_db; init_db()
>>> exit()
```

The trick is that when you run Python it only looks in a certain number of places for [modules and packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) - you can see which places by running:

```
>>> from sys import path
>>> for fp in path:
...     print fp
```

from the Python interpreter.  If the path to flaskr is not in that list flaskr can't be imported.  By default Python adds the directory it is started in to its search path (which is why we start Python in the directory that contains flaskr.)

Once you have run `init_db` you should be able to run the application and see everything working.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick turnaround!  That was a very helpful explanation, and I was able to get the app up and running.  Thanks again.

Comment: @JamieB - glad I can help!  Enjoy the tutorial.

Comment: When I do the import via the Python interpreter I get `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Comment: Here's a solution to my problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/265gdi/flask_runtime_error_with_database_initialization/

Answer (score 24):

The thing that fixed it for me was changing

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
```

to

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr.py
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1902)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a version of Flask < 0.11, the `flask` command is not available. Install the `flask-cli` package in that case.

```
pip install flask-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

To anyone else who finds this, add `init_db()` to the main executer to the end of your `flaksr` app as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    app.run()
```

That should solve the sqlite error and stop you from having to run `init_db()` manually.

Answer (score 2):

When we say :

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
```

by no means python understands where the package "flaskr.py" exists.

One of the way to solve the issue is choosing the right path where the "flaskr.py" resides. For eg, change your current working directory to where the file exists and :

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
```

Then you can execute "flask run" anywhere you want.

PS: flask tutorial seems broken. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sean Viera's answer was very good, although I'd like to add that I was encountering the same problem and want to add to the solution.  Running Python from the same flaskr folder was not enough for me.  It was also necessary to activate Flask before running $Python by running the ". venv/bin/activate" command, like so:

```
$ cd path/to/flaskr
#active 
$ . venv/bin/activate 
(venv)$ python

# Python then runs and you can import flaskr
>>> from flaskr import init_db; 
>>> init_db()
>>> exit()
$
```

Hope that extra bit of info helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$set FLASK_APP=flaskr
$python -m flask initdb
$python -m flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

OS: Windows

```
(venv)$pip install -I --no-deps Flask
(venv)$set FLASK_APP=flaskr
(venv)$set FLASK_DEBUG=1
(venv)$flask run
```

Explain:

`$where flask` will help to locate *flask.exe*

if virtual-env inherits *flask* from system-env

```
(venv)$where flask
>> /system/environment/path/to/flask.exe

(root)$where flask
>> /system/environment/path/to/flask.exe
```

obviously it calls *flask.exe* which is installed for system-env

`(venv)$pip install -I Flask` can force to (re)install *flask* for virtual-env

```
(venv)$pip install -I Flask
(venv)$where flask
>> /virtual/environment/path/to/flask.exe
>> /system/environment/path/to/flask.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I have fixed it by.
step1:

1. sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python
2. easy_install_3.4 flask.
3. PYTHONPATH=`pwd`

step2: using easy_install_3.4 to install falsk.
step3:

## Heading

Comment: export befor running  PYTHONPATH=`pwd` flask run